# Exception when generating sequence using Eclipselink and h2 in test environment

Tags: eclipselink, integration-testing, h2, jboss-arquillian, weblogic12c

I'm using h2 to setup an integration test for an application using Eclipselink, Arquillian and Weblogic 12.1.1

This is my entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AFIS_REQUEST")
public class Request implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "requestSEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "requestSEQ", sequenceName = "REQUEST_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;
...
}
```

And this is my persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="myPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/arquillian</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.my.Request</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <validation-mode>NONE</validation-mode>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>            
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINEST"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.H2Platform"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

And here is my JDBC URL and Driver class specified in Weblogic data source:

- jdbc:h2:file:target/databases/h2/db
- org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource

But when I start my test I get following exception:

```
<Dec 3, 2012 3:58:23 PM IRST> <Warning> <EclipseLink> <BEA-2005000> <2012-12-03 15:58:23.217--ServerSession(16406343)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Sequence "REQUEST_ID_SEQ" not found; SQL statement:
CALL NEXT VALUE FOR REQUEST_ID_SEQ [90036-166]
Error Code: 90036
Call: CALL NEXT VALUE FOR REQUEST_ID_SEQ
Query: ValueReadQuery(sql="CALL NEXT VALUE FOR REQUEST_ID_SEQ")>
```

Because I want the table to be created when starting the tests and to be dropped when finishing the tests I have assigned `drop-and-create-tables` to `eclipselink.ddl-generation` property. But it seems that Table is generated but it's sequence is not created by Eclipselink.

Does h2 support generating sequences? or am i missing any configuration?

**EDIT:**
I checked the generated DDL and it shows that the create sequence statement is generated.

```
CREATE TABLE REQUEST (ID BIGINT NOT NULL, ... , PRIMARY KEY (ID))
CREATE SEQUENCE REQUEST_ID_SEQ START WITH 1
```

Then I connected to generated database using H2 web console and saw that sequences are generated and I could execute `CALL NEXT VALUE FOR REQUEST_ID_SEQ` successfully there!

So why Eclipselink is complaining about it!? `Sequence "REQUEST_ID_SEQ" not found;`

Comment: Everything looks fine here. You might have some luck if you could output the DDL generated by EclipseLink using the [output-mode config property](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/DDL), to verify that EclipseLink actually generates a sequence.

Comment: Thanks Vineet, I updated the question based on your comment.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure if this is the cause, but you don't seem to have any Entity classes listed in persistence.xml, although you have a `exclude-unlisted-classes` element defined as true. If you have a reproducible test case that I can work on, I wouldn't mind taking a look at it.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the problem, but could you try with an absolute database URL, or relative to the user home directory, so for example `jdbc:h2:file:~/temp/databases/h2/db`?

Comment: I created a bug report for the unnecessary warnings: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=470284 I guess it will need some votes to get fixed...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and i managed to get this working, just add this line to your persistence file :

```
<property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.H2Platform"/>
```

It MUST be the first property of `<properties>`.

Note that you will still have the warning.

I found the solution [here](http://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#using_eclipselink)

Comment: Any idea how to get rid of the warning?